# Is this condition necessary for a function $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to be differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Consider the following definitions:

> A function $f : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $U$ is an open set) is **differentiable at a point** $a \in U$ if there exists a linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{v \to 0} \dfrac{f(a+v) - f(a) - T(v)}{\|v\|} = 0$$
>
> ---
>
> The **directional derivative** of $f$ at $a$ in the direction of $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) = \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(a+tv) - f(a)}{t}$$

Now, it is easy to show that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial (\alpha v)}(a) = \alpha\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)$ for any $v$ and $\alpha \neq 0$ (if it exists).

It is also easy to show that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)$ exists for all $v$, with the special property that

$$\forall \, v,w \in \mathbb{R^m} \qquad \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial (v + w)}(a) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial w}(a)$$

So far so good.

Now, there is an equivalent definition of differentiability at a point, as follows:

> **(Alternative Definition)** A function $f : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $U$ is an open set) is differentiable at a point $a \in U$ if all the following conditions hold:
>
> - For all $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ the directional derivative $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)$ exists.
> - For all $v,w \in \mathbb{R^m}$, we have $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial (v + w)}(a) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a) + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial w}(a)$.
> - $\lim_\limits{v \to 0} \dfrac{f(a+v) - f(a) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)}{\|v\|} = 0$

I also understand that this definition is equivalent to the first one. So far so good.

**But is the second bullet on the Alternative Definition necessary? Or does it follow from the first and third bullets?**

Answer (score 0):

The second bullet doesn't follow from the first and the third. Let $n = m = 1$ and consider the function $f(x) = |x|$ at $x = 0$. The directional derivatives are

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(0) = \lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(tv) - f(0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|tv|}{t} = |v| $$

and we have

$$ \lim_{v \to 0} \frac{f(0 + v) - f(0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(0)}{|v|} = \lim_{v \to 0} \frac{|v| - |v| }{|v|} = 0$$

but the map $v \mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(0)$ is not additive.

BTW, if $v \mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)$ happens to be differentiable at $v = 0$ then this (together with the homogeneity of the map) forces $v \mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)$ to be linear.

Comment: Hello, sorry to take so long to give your post some attention. Unfortunately, you made a mistake in your first step. The limit is not $t \to 0^+$, but $t \to 0$, and this makes a huge difference: the directional derivatives in fact do not exist (since they would be $|v|$ or $-|v|$ depending on how you approach zero). Therefore, your example doesn't work because your function does not satisfy the first bullet... Can you think of another example, please? :)